# Maven places JAR under Projects instead of Library for project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have one main project and 2 other projects that the main one will use. The 2 projects are packaged into a `.jar` file.

In the main project, I am placing these 2 JAR files into `/src/main/resources/lib`. I have the following in the `pom.xml`:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>MainProject</warName>
        <outputDirectory>dist</outputDirectory>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <webResources> 
            <resource> 
                <directory>src/main/resources/lib</directory> 
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath> 
            </resource> 
        </webResources> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>

...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/project1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/project2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I then run the command: `mvn clean package eclipse:eclipse -DskipTests=true`

When I refresh the project in Eclipse and look at the Project properties, `Project1` is under the Library tab and `Project2` is under the Projects tab and saying "missing".

Why would there be a difference? Is it how the JAR files are created?

Thank you again SO community for the help!

**UPDATE**

I looked at the `.classpath` file and see that the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is putting the `Project2` in incorrectly.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/resources/lib/project1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/project2"/>
```

Comment: Are those other projects maven projects?

Comment: Yes they are. Need anything from their POM?

Comment: I also checked both `.project` files and they are the same, except one used CheckStyle. So they both seems to be the same project type.

Comment: Chances are, you have the `project2` on your workspace and have the m2e `workspace resolution` turned on, so the main project refers to `Project2`'s source. You can turn off the feature by right clicking the project and selecting `Disable Workspace Resolution` option from the `Maven` option of the context-menu.

Comment: I am not using Maven in Eclipse. I actually use the command line tool

Comment: So I found out the issue, which still doesn't quite make sense. The name of Project2 actually has a dash in it for the `artifactId`. By removing the dash, it worked!? Not sure why.